# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in Electron

Tags: ssl, windows-10, ssl-certificate, electron

I am trying to connect to the localhost via https. Since on production it will be replaced with a proper IP with a valid SSL, but on localhost it is throwing Error on electron.

[image]

How to avoid the error by suppressing the SSL check, just on the localhost for the testing , which i will remove on production.Please help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chris gave an exact explanation. Just posting the code for the same

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 900,
        height: 680,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false
        }
});
//second alternative
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
```

Comment: I think `webSecurity : false` is not recommended. `second alternative works`. That too required if you are working with self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 2):

In your `BrowserWindow` object set `webPreferences.allowRunningInsecureContent` to true and `webPreferences.webSecurity` to false. That should suppress those errors.

More info: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

If that doesn't resolve the issue, have a look at this documentation about bypassing certificate errors: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-certificate-error

Comment: Not sure it's so much certificate error as a lack of SSL support entirely on localhost. Those properties do nothing in this context; they're for mixing HTTP and HTTPS items on the same page and breaking same-origin requirements. OP needs to install SSL on the server. This isn't a huge amount of work, and a self-signed certificate will work just fine for this.